# Validate an IP before using scp

Tags: bash, ip-address, scp

I'm writing a file transfer script and it gets pretty complex.  So in the beginning when I generate my IP address to transfer from, I want to validate that I can indeed connect to it.  The code in the area looks like this:

```
USER_ID=$1
if [[ $GROUP == "A" ]]; then
    ADDRESS="${USER_ID}@morgan.company.gov"
elif [[ $GROUP == "B" ]]; then
    ADDRESS="${USER_ID}@mendel.company.gov"
else
    log_msg fatal "Couldn't resolve group $GROUP. Exiting"
    exit 1;
fi

// HERE I want to test that $ADDRESS exists, and I can connect right now I
// have what is below.  I just think there is a better way to do it

ssh -q $ADDRESS exit
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    log_msg fatal "Couldn't resolve host, do you have login privileges with $ADDRESS"
fi

... // lots of other things happen

scp $ADDRESS:$INCOMING_FILE $NEW_FILE
```

What I have works, but it doesn't seem like its an elegant solution.  I'd prefer not to actually ssh and exit the server, just test the connection.

Comment: What do you want to test exactly? You can test that you can connect to it with `ping` but that won't necessarily work and won't test the connection to port 22. You can test the port with `nc` but that won't tell you if ssh/scp (as opposed to something else) is actually available on the other end. `nc` also won't tell you if your ssh keys are set up correctly or not. I'm not even sure using `ssh` is guaranteed to be a valid test (since you may have forced commands/etc. that prevent non-`scp` usage but that's not likely and you probably can rule that out by "spec" as it were).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this shell function that tests wether the host has the ssh port open or not:

```
#!/bin/bash
function isUp(){
    local ip=$1
    local sshport=22
    if [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        if [[ $(nmap -P0 $ip -p$sshport | grep ^$sshport | cut -d' ' -f2) == "open" ]]; then
            return 0
        else
            return 1
        fi
    fi
}
if isUp $1; then
    ssh $1 uptime
else
    echo "Host $1 is not available"
fi
```

or make use of this (new to me) bash functionality:

```
#!/bin/bash
function isUp(){
   local ip=$1
   if echo > /dev/tcp/$ip/22 >/dev/null 2>&1; then
      return 0
   else
      return 1
   fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to thoroughly check for the connection then you are better off analyzing the [return codes from an `scp` connection](http://support.attachmate.com/techdocs/2487.html). This will allow you to understand the reason why your connection failed and act in consequence (there may be various reasons at different levels, from a general lack of connectivity to issues with the keys for instance).

If you are just interested in a binary answer ("is my connection OK as it is?") then your code is fine, though I would directly use `scp`.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your line:

```
ssh -q $ADDRESS exit
```

This is the best/fastest way to test a connection.